# JavaScript (jquery): load new document in window.opener

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.opener

I have a parent window, when user clicks on link "Compare All" a JS popup (colorbox) opens and displays the photos and its information.

When user clicks on popup (child window) link "See this item", I need to load in parent
window the page about this item, wait before document will be ready and close the child window after.

Below just an example script in child window (not working):

```
window.opener.location.href = url;  // working fine

$(window.opener.document).ready(function() {

window.close();

});
```

Please let me know how I can to do this right? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to wait before closing the window? i would just close it immediately.

Comment: I need to wait before document will be ready

Comment: My question is *Why* do you need to wait for the document to be ready. Does it take 6 seconds for the page to open?

Comment: Yes. I tried the following, but it is not pretty:

Comment: window.setTimeout(function() {
window.close();
}, 3000);

Comment: use a setInterval that repeatedly checks for some property to appear on the window.opener

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.opener.location.href = 'https://www.yourpage.com.ar';      
    window.close();
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation!?

Comment: @WernerHenze I do agree, the answer should include any explanation on what exactly the code does and how it solves the problem. Anyhow I do believe, you can formulate this somewhat nicer. For some people this might be offending, even if just slightly.